# formula for the average of the coefficients of a power series

Tags: power-series, average

In Über analytische Funktionen und die Verteilung von Zahlen mod. eins;
Abhandlungen aus dem Mathematischen Seminar der Universität Hamburg v. 1, pp. 54–76, 1922,

Hecke says *it is a well-known result that*

$\lim_{r \rightarrow 1}(1-r)\sum_{m=1}^\infty c_m r^m = \lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{t}\sum_{m=1}^t c_m$

How do you prove that?